# Modify controller context while rendering a razor view to a string

Tags: c#, razor

Rendering a view to a string has been asked many times, however my question differs.

The `ViewEngineResult.View` has a method called `Render(ViewContext, TextWriter)`

My code works fine if I pass in the controller which houses my email views, however if the action method originated on another controller then I need to be able to modify the ViewContext to look in the EmailControllers views.

I can't figure out exactly what property the `Render` method is using to figure out what view folders to look in. Essentially i'm looking to figure that out so I can tell it to look in the Email views folder.

Here's my code for reference:

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        var oldModel = controller.ViewData.Model;
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        try
        {
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName,
                                                                           null);

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                controller.ViewData.Model = oldModel;
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

So to recap, If I pass in the orders controller the `FindView` looks for my view within the Orders view folder, I need to tell it to look in the Email view folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewEngine looks at the `RouteData` to determine what `.cshtml` file to load. Specifically the `controller` and `action` properties. You could (and probably recommended) pass in the controller name you wish to use but you can see I've hard coded it to `Email` for now in the code below.

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    var oldModel = controller.ViewData.Model;
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    try
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {

            controller.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Email";

            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, null);

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);

            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            controller.ViewData.Model = oldModel;
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

### More stuff if you really want to know

Razor has several locations it looks for when trying to determine which view to use. `{0}` here is the action (or passed in view name) and `{1}` is the controller.

```
        ViewLocationFormats = new[] { 
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
```

Same as here except we also have `{2}` which is the area.

```
        AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" 
        };
```

All of these parameters come from the RouteData (unless specifically overwritten via parameter such as `View("viewname")`. They're specifically `action`, `controller` and `area`. By modifying these values you can alter several ways MVC works. Including determining which controller to use before one is selected. Same with actions and areas.

Hope this helps.